# java class reference issue between two jars

Tags: java, apache-poi, birt

I have a java class to process XLS file and using apache poi jar (poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar) to do so. Also i have recently deployed BIRT jar's to generate some reports. Here onwards when i call my java class for XLS processing, getting the below error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(Ljava/io/File;)Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook;
```

i found that 'WorkbookFactory' class is also available in BIRT related jars (org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.2.1.v20120918-1113.jar) and the specified method is not available in this jar. This might be causing the above exception.

How to resolve this issue by having both the jars(POI and BIRT) deployed in server.

Comment: Which version of BIRT and POI are you using?

Comment: If you re-arrange your classpath to look for the class in the POI jar first (simply mention it before mentioning the BIRT jar in the classpath declaration), this issue may get resolved. Of course I'm assuming that it wouldn't introduce further conflict from utilizing POI classes when BIRT classes are expected.

Comment: Can you not get a newer version of BIRT that uses the same version of POI as you want to use?

Comment: Tried to remove poi package from BIRT?

Comment: @OlegMikheev: No i could not remove as there is a lot to check with dependencies.

Comment: @hemanth: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @SayemAhmed; am in process to remove POI related classes from BIRT jar instead of changing the class path details or loading class files from a specific jar by using Java URI classes. Seems BIRT 4.3 will come with POI 3.9 which will give complete resolution. However i cant wait for that. Hence removing POI files from BIRT jar itself.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with BIRT 4.4 that uses POI 3.9, while I was using POI 3.13.

As I am using Maven, I simply made use of "Exclude Maven Artifact" in the Maven Dependencies section, to get rid of the older version of POI without impacting the overall BIRT dependencies.

I hope this won't impact BIRT's integrity.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a newer version of BIRT that pulls in a more recent copy of Apache POI? (And/or hassle them until there is one...)

Comment: You'll need to speak to the folks behind BIRT then, and ask them for a new release bumping up that dependency version. [Hopefully the number of bug fixes in the last 3 years](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.9) will make them realise why they need to upgrade!

Comment: Yes, I contacted them yesterday and still waiting their response.